# ASP.NET authentication on one database, with authorization roles stored on separate databases for each customer

Tags: c#, asp.net, multiple-databases, asp.net-roles

We have a database architecture where one database stores account information for authentication. We then have a separate instance of our application data database for each customer (for data portability, auditing, and to support upgrades to on-premise deployments). We're currently adding support for multiple user roles, and we'd like to store the data for user authorizations in the appropriate database for the customer.

Is this possible in ASP.NET authorization?

I've tried:

1. Overriding the connection string that's part of the configuration for RoleManager in web.config. This approach didn't work because the code would be executed too early in the application life-cycle (I didn't yet have the information regarding the current user identity).
2. I wrote an attribute class for API controller methods that would grab the configuration information and update the connection string. This was hacky, possibly insecure, and persisting the update required saving over the configuration file, which I believe would trigger a restart of the application every time.

I need a more flexible way to indicate which database is associated with the current user, and to use that database as the role provider database for that user.

Comment: Is the user (with email, password, etc) table in each of the customer's databases? Or do you have one specific database to store users data for all clients?

Comment: The latter. The **authentication** information is stored in one database. But we'd like to store the **authorization** roles in the appropriate customer database.

Comment: Are you using **ASP.NET Identity** or something else?

Comment: Yes, we are using ASP.NET Identity.